# Is thera a way to pass NULL value to Crystal Reports programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, null, crystal-reports-2010

It is VS 2010 version.

CR is able to accept NULL values, because when it prompts me for parameter values, there is cute little check box which says 'Set to NULL'. This is behavior that I need.

But, I almost never call reports like that, I do it in code. So, if a user does not provide a value for a parameter, I would like to pass NULL value in its place, so I could do something differently in report itself.

I've searched around net for ages, mostly in CR forums, and I've got number of solution, non of which actually works.

This is one of them:

```
ParameterDiscreteValue objDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
objDiscreteValue.Value = null;
rptH.SetParameterValue(parName, new ParameterDiscreteValue(objDiscreteValue));
```

CR says you haven't provided a value for ... parameter.

I muscle solve it by creating double parameters. One real parameter, and one satellite parameter for it (boolean value, only to see if there is a value for real parameter). And it works. But it is tedious, and makes my generics (automatic prompting for parameters based on report metadata) very very hard.

I am hoping someone has dug deep enough to find a solution for this problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I did this with VS.2005, but i think it's the same problem. From experience, we didn't have any trouble with `VARCHAR` data type, but the problem arises when we use the `Number` data type.

For `VARCHAR` Data Type, you just pass an empty String to the parameter. For example, I have parameter within SQL Server with data type `VARCHAR` as below:

`MyParamFields.Add(AddParamReport("@TheActiveYear", mTahunAktiv, ParameterValueKind.StringParameter))`

In this case, if I want to pass `NULL` value I just give empty string to `mTahunAktiv` variable within my VB.Net Code, like this `mTahunAktiv=""`. and the CR suggest this as null value and give the right result.

For kind of `Number` Data Type, it's little tricky. I think this is the best way for now, same as you I've googled but never know the solution yet.

For example in my case I have a parameter for passing *Month in number value* with data type `SMALLINT`, but sometimes a user needs the value as `NULL`. To overcome the problem I just send a value, example 13 to that parameter, but before that you must handle it in the SQL QUERY, if you give the 13 value to that parameter it becomes NULL. For this, I am using STORED PROCEDURE with dynamic Filtering Parameter. For me this can solve my problem.

I'm not sure if you will understand what I mean, but I hope this little exprience can help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon DBValue.Null from ADO.NET DataSets and it sparked me to try to pass that to Crystal, and voila, it works. Just like this:

```
ParameterDiscreteValue objDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
objDiscreteValue.Value = DBNull.Value;
rptH.SetParameterValue(parName, objDiscreteValue);
```

I hope this helps to someone, but I think this should be documented somewhere.

Best Regards,